# error while computing height of element in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a simple code for computing the height of an image

```
<div id="container" class="container-container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="main" class="span7">
            <div id="div1">
                <img src="http://s0.uploads.im/LtBsp.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

In IE and Firefox the height of image is computing well, but in chrome I get an error:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var h = $('#div1').height();
    $('#test').html(h);
});    
</script>
```

Error in event handler for 'undefined':

```
IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
at M (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:17:154)
at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:19:417
at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:165
at <error: illegal access>
```

Comment: That's good to know. What's the question?

Comment: why IE and firefox are worked well, but in chrome this code doesnt work...

Comment: Then copy a paste this in your question: `"Why does this code works fine in Internet Explorer (#ie_version) and Mozilla Firefox (#ff_version) but not in Google Chrome (#gc_version)?"`

Comment: come on your are spending too mutch time with computers, you will finish thinking like one. lol . the text, at the end is enough clear for any intelligent human being to deduce the question : "in IE and firefox the height of image is computing well, but in chrome i have an error".  "Elementary my dear Watson"

Comment: The problem is that there are rules in this community. Yes, the question was deducible, but wasn't following the community rules.

Comment: all browser is last version

Comment: It is ok, I was just kidding ;). Only dont forget that humans do errors and there is a really extraordinary concept behind that all  
great scientific discoveries and inventions where done when rules where broken, dont forget that ;) (it is the basic principle of genetic evolution too ;))

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/NG4Hg/

Comment: yes, but in my project doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is clashing with one installed extension, first temporary deactivate the chrome extensions, and run the code.

if you are in an event handler you can always use:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

at the end of your code.

Comment: i disable all extension and use `e.preventDefault();
` at the end of code, but this not any effect.

Comment: The code is working in my browser. This must be something specific to your browser.

Comment: can you more explain about  `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: prevent default is used to avoid the browser calling the default handler of the  event, normally it is equivalent of doing : return false; at the end of your handler.

Comment: do you have the Google Dictionary extention installed in your chrome? (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja)

Comment: can you introduce an reference about handler &  `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: I have the same problem. When i uninstall the google dictionary, problem solved. Thank you @ElLocoCocoLoco :)